# Hack for `mouseup` outside of window in IE 7/8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I understand the event `mouseup` for the window just isn't there for IE 7 and 8. I was wondering if anybody has found a work-around for this or if that is even possible.

I am currently working on a project where the user can click, drag to draw a line, and if the user drags outside of the window **and** lets up on the mouse, the drawing transaction will be cancelled.

Comment: Since there is a security bug filed for IE (all versions) tracking/providing mouse movements outside the browser window (even if the app doesn't have focus!) http://spider.io/blog/2012/12/internet-explorer-data-leakage/ we (the dev community) are fully expecting this behavior to be fixed in all versions of IE.  Thus at this point I would be incredibly precautious of depending on events fired beyond the browser window.

Comment: ...However Microsoft (well aware of their position in the online ad world) is taking a wait and see approach: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/12/13/update-to-alleged-information-and-security-issue-with-mouse-position-behavior.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your difficulty sounds like it would be more from the window losing the scope of the event.

Are you using jQuery?  With jQuery you can also tag onto the mousemove event and use the "which" attribute to detect if the button is pressed.  This even fires when you come back into the window.  But it DOES NOT fire when you are outside of the window.

Alternatively you can use $(window).mouseleave to detect when it leaves the window.  However once it has left the window you cannot detect further mouse events (that would be a horrible flaw if they could detect when you right clicked on your desktop etc).

So you are somewhat limited by the browser security implementations in ALL browsers and won't be able to bypass that... but you can add some work around events to provide a "similar" experience.

Comment: We are using Dojo 1.7. I was thinking of using the `mouseleave` event of the window but that does match the functionality in other browsers. There is _sort-of_ a way to detect mouse events outside the window in some browsers. We have already implemented the window.onmouseup event which is registered when the user `mousedown`s in the canvas.

Comment: Cool, Dojo, Mootools or jQuery at least you are using something to abstract away the browser differences.  In this case I think the bear is going to be in "trying" to detect any/some events with the mouse outside of the browser.

Comment: I figured, but it was at least worth a shot asking! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but I believe this should work.

In your `mousemove` event, check the `Event.buttons` property. If it is zero, then the user must have released the mouse outside the window and you can cancel the drag.

I am checking the browser compatibility of this now, so this answer may be edited. My computer's being slow right now!